# ffmpeg include error - github project

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to compile (IDE:VS2008) the following project: 
https://github.com/arpu/adscanner

As the project needs the ffmpeg libaries, I've downloaded the DEV version from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I've linked the library directions and added the headers to the include path.

Though I get the error message: ""ffmpeg/avcodec.h": No such file or directory"

Thank you in advance

PS: I've tried both the 64bit and 32bit library, neither worked. But how can I figure it out weather the github project is using the 32bit or 64bit ffmpeg version?

Answer (score 0):

Change this in ffmpeg_movie.h

```
extern "C" { 
#include <ffmpeg/avcodec.h>
#include <ffmpeg/avformat.h>
#include <ffmpeg/swscale.h>
}
```

to this

```
extern "C"{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

and when i last used ffmpeg i had to add this

```
extern "C"{
#ifdef __cplusplus
 #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
 #ifdef _STDINT_H
  #undef _STDINT_H
 #endif
 # include <stdint.h>
#endif
}
# include <stdio.h>
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
#define UINT64_C(c) (c ## ULL)
#endif
```